# REST API only allow connections from static domain

Tags: rest, amazon-web-services, aws-api-gateway, restful-architecture

I would like to know if it is possible to lock down a list of REST services to a static domain name;

My end goal would be to have my list of public services accessible ONLY from our AWS API Gateway domain address, nothing else.

We currently have a list of public facing endpoints;

- https://serviceaddress/api/v1/getSomething
- https://serviceaddress/api/v1/postSomething
- https://serviceaddress/api/v1/deleteSomething

I would like to lock all services down to a specific domain address:

- https://mydomain/api/v1/service

This cannot be done via the backend service code and should be more from an infrastructure point of view (eg: blacklisting all except this domain on a NAT / ec2 instance).

Things I have tried and know would do the job but don't help:

- Using SSL certificates
- Using custom headers
- Use a Lambda via VPC (no point as these are already external endpoints)

Each of these would require code changes to the existing services.

I thought this would be a simple case of locking down any calls coming to an endpoint (the service being called) to a domain or set of whitelisted IP address.

I'm just not sure where to start?

Comment: It is not clear what you mean by lock down "to a static domain."  Do you mean you don't want your backend services to respond unless the request comes to them **through** an API Gateway endpoint?  Or... perhaps it would be clearer if you can define exactly what it is that you want to prevent.

Answer (score 0):

CloudFront -- API Gateway -- Rest Endpoints would be the cleaner configuration.

You can avoid cloudfront if you want to go through process of custom domains under API Gateway.

Create a HTTP proxy in APIGateway under,

https://mydomain/api/v1/service -- GET -- https://serviceaddress/api/v1/getSomething

and similarly for other methods.

More documentation,

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/api-gateway-create-api-as-simple-proxy-for-http.html

Comment: Thanks but this won't help.
We currently have an API Gateway custom domain setup (this is the one in question). There are a bunch of endpoints setup within that API Gateway, each calling a backend service. I would like that backend service to accept calls only from this API Gateway domain and no one else (the backend services are public facing).
The proxy isn't the problem, we already have many, its locking the backend services down to only that API Gateway domain.

Comment: You want to disable access to backend services directly and enable access only to that domain?

Comment: Correct, and as mentioned making then internal and using VPC is not an option

Comment: There are two ways you can do it. Only via custom authorizers. And other via enabling API Keys. Custom Authorizers needs code and API Keys needs custom headers added to those calls. You can route from Cloudfront with Additional Headers to API Gateway and keep the backend services secured.

Comment: Thanks for trying Kannaiyans however, we already have a custom authoriser and use API keys, these don't help if the endpoints are still public.. You can do what ever you'd like in the authoriser, the backend services will still accept calls from other domains / IP addresses. I'm hoping someone has had to lock down API services to an IP range or domain, which would help.

Comment: @Hexie you would lock down the backend services to only accept calls from API Gateway using a client SSL certificate. http://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/getting-started-client-side-ssl-authentication.html

Comment: @MarkB Thanks for the suggestion Mark, but as mentioned in the question, I have already considered that as an option, however, it would mean updating each service endpoint, which is not ideal in this situation. Hence, I'm looking to do it on a more of an infrastructure point of view if possible.

Comment: You can't leave the endpoints completely pubic but somehow magically make them private. What network level or service do you expect to solve this issue for you?

Comment: @MarkB I understand, it sounds bizarre hence my research into it. I read somewhere that you could possibly do it with EC2 instances if all the services run through that - however, I think that would be over kill. I was hoping for something like a NAT / Infrastructure design that would block all requests to an address and whitelist only what you'd like (seeing as though everything is static and known, i.e. the address and domain).

Comment: The fact is you need to make the servers private (this can be done entirely at the network/vpc level without any code changes), then place something in front of those servers that can handle the requests and block unwanted traffic. Many different things can do that, but not until you make the servers private. You could use an EC2 server, ELB+WAF, or something similar. Just block public access via security group rules and move your DNS to point to the intermediary.

Comment: Thanks @MarkB I'm going to look a little more into possibly using certificates before going down the WAF route, ideally i'd like to do this with no need for backend code changes but a certificate might just be the simplest and best approach. I appreciate the help so far